# How to send Logs to CloudWatch from a iOS App?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a iOS App and want to log some things for example when an error happened. Is there a possibility to send those Logs to Cloudwatch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `AWSLogs` SDK to send logs from an iOS app to CloudWatch. Add the following line to your Podfile under the app target section to consume the SDK via cocoapods:

```
pod 'AWSLogs', '~> 2.7'
```

Documentation: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSLogs
Source: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSLogs

To instantiate the client, do the following:

```
let logs = AWSLogs.default()
```

Once you have the logs client created, you need to create a log group and log stream. You can do this via Amazon CloudWatch Logs console or through the SDK. If you want to create using the SDK, do the following:

**Create a log group:**

https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSLogs.html#//api/name/createLogGroup:

**Create a log stream:**

https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSLogs.html#//api/name/createLogStream:

Now, you can start sending the logs to the log stream. You need a sequence token which you can obtain by doing a `DescribeLogStreams` call. See https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSLogs.html#//api/name/DescribeLogStreams:

After this you can call `putLogEvents` in order to send the logs:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSLogs.html#//api/name/putLogEvents:

You can take a look at our tests for an example: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSLogsUnitTests/AWSGeneralLogsTests.m#L1247

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Karthikeyan I am getting AccessDeniedException when executing putLogEvents. I think, that additional set-up is needed in the AWS console. Do you know how to achieve it?